# SCTP missing include file on OSX?

Tags: macos, sockets, networking, include, sctp

I was messing around with sockets, and I wanted to test out using the SCTP protocol on my mac.

However, when I try to include the file `netinet/sctp.h` the compiler gives me a 'file not found' error.

So I did some digging, and sure enough, there is no include file for `netinet/sctp.h` on Mac OSX Lion. Why is that, when I can set up a socket with `IPPROTO_SCTP`, and it builds fine?

So, in summary, I have two questions:

- Where are the headers for SCTP on Mac OSX?
- Can  I still set up a SCTP server without the proper headers? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Lion `IPPROTO_SCTP` is defined in `netinet/in.h` - that's why it worked just fine since you probably included `netinet/in.h` directly or indirectly. However, it is only present in Lion, not in any earlier OS X versions. (Note that `netinet/sctp.h` is not part of POSIX an I don't think it's portable)

Comment: Interesting. So does this mean I cannot use SCTP to set up a client-server socket on my Mac?

Comment: I fear not without a library - no sctp-specific functions are provided by OS X and creating a `IPPROTO_SCTP` sockets leads to `Protocol not supported` error.

Comment: Just for completeness, you can run SCTP on OS X with a 3rd party extension: http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could do

```
brew install libusrsctp
```

And you will see the installed header here, although it is probably a different implementation with a different name:

```
cat /usr/local/Cellar/libusrsctp/0.9.5.0/include/usrsctp.h
```